# How to set permission for uploading in PHP script [Windows]

Tags: php, windows, file-upload

I have coded PHP script for uploading JPEG file. It works for uploading but when I open that file, it show that

> Photo Gallery can't open this photo because you do not have
>   permission to access the file location

How can I set the permission after uploading code for Windows?

```
<?php
$target_dir = "/fileUpload";

$name = $_POST['txtname'];

$target_file = $target_dir . basename($name) . ".jpg";
$imageupload = $_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'];  

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'],$target_file)){
    //for linux, chmod($target_file, 0777);
    //for windows?
    echo("yes");
}else{
    echo("no");
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you testing on an Administrator account on Windows and still having issues?

Comment: @BrandonWhite Yes, I have tested on Administrator account and got this issue.

Answer (score 0):

First of all - you should never run any web server under an elevated account. It is a huge security flaw.

Regarding your actual question - you don't tell which web server you use. The most often used combination is IIS+PHP as FCGI. For that, IIS uses a technique called impersonation and starts processes under a virtual identitiy that can get permissions assigned. That virtual identity is often named similar to DefaultAppPool, depends how many sites you have. As well, that virtual identity can own files, etc. You should ensure that you've set permissions correctly on all the directories that you want to be accessed by it - like temporary dir, actual upload dir, etc. You can read more about it fe here http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities

If you run under Apache/NGINX - the story is similar, you should compare the process identity and ensure that it can do desired operations on filesystem objects.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for missing details. I have run under Appserv and the destination of uploading file is in drive C.  <br/>  PS.I cannot set uploading into Appserv folder because it will not appear though the function is success.